# Manage variables php on MVC

Tags: php

I want print on screen variable content of this:

```
$this->texto("Hello");
```

(in this case, Hello)
I'm trying learn about MVC, but don't know how send variables and print it.

I have this controller:

```
class Lang extends Controller
{

    public $variable;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->view->texto = [];
    }

    function render()
    {
        /*
         * $langs = $this->model->get($string);
         * $this->view->texto = $langs;
         * $this->view->render('lang/index');
         */
        echo $variable;
    }
}
```

And no good results, how fix it?